# Coordinate systems over products of $n$-spheres

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, spheres

To be specific, I have four 4-spheres, that is, for each of the spheres, we have a relation of the form,
\begin{equation}
x_1^2 +x_2^2 +x_3^2 +x_4^2 =1.
\end{equation}
So, I have twelve degrees of freedom in total. Further, I have a function defined over these four 4-spheres. I can, of course, parameterize each of the spheres individually using hyperspherical coordinates. But are there coordinate systems developed that would allow me to treat the twelve variables in some "global/unified" fashion? Of course, the product of two 2-spheres (circles) is a torus. So, it would seem that I am looking for some generalization/extension of coordinates tailored to a torus.

The twelve-variate function in which I am interested in studying, arose in the course of computing the (Moore) determinant of a $4 \times 4$ Hermitian matrix with its off-diagonal entries being quaternions, except for the 
(1,2)-(2,1) and (3,4)-(4-3) pairs which are set to zero.

Comment: The "usual" coordinates on a torus are precisely the product of separate coordinates on circles; they only look nice/unified because the universal cover of a circle is a line. Spheres of higher dimension are simply-connected, so there's no analogue of covering a torus by a plane. That said, products of stereographic projections or generalized spherical coordinates for your $3$-spheres can be written explicitly without trouble.